# Zend Framework: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'

Tags: windows, zend-framework

As you may have known that I switched from ubuntu to windows from my previous questions. I was working on Zend Framework on ubuntu and now working on same project in windows. Because of this switching I am facing some problems in windows which was not occurred in ubuntu.

Now I have the following error in firebug console when I go to login page:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in <b>C:\wamp\www\vcred\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br />
```

Do you people know that what type of error is this and what is the solution?

I have the following configuration for database.

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "test"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks related to this bug on PHP's bugtracker : **[Bug #47224 `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` is no longer available](http://bugs.php.net/47224)**

It seems it's been fixed in SVN -- but maybe not in the version of PHP you are using ?

Quoting one of the comments :

> [2009-07-02 06:43 UTC] mg at artigo
>   dot pl 
> A temporary solution is to
>   use INT value (`1002`) instead of
>   constant.

This might be a temporary solution, until you install a new version of PHP, in which the bug is fixed ?

Comment: Ok. first I try the latest WAMP.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error with PHP 5.2.6, and all I had to do is to open **`php.ini`** (e.g. on Windows: *C:\Windows\php.ini*, or on Ubuntu: */etc/php5/apache2/php.ini* or sg. like this) in a text editor, and **remove the semicolon from the following line**:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

So as a result it would look like this in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: I'm glad. But I would be curious why someone downvoted this answer without giving a reason...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [Windows bug in PHP 5.3](http://bugs.php.net/47224) that was fixed in SVN a while ago.  You might want to try updating to the latest PHP release to see if the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, on debian6, when I had not yet installed `php-mysql` so, I simply installed this, like this

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I just add it here, in case other have same problem, to save them them a few minutes of research.